# bootstrap cdn for china specific

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap in china, but I am not sure is this a legitimate site, have others used it or are others using it.

https://www.bootcdn.cn/twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

OK, the overall domestic Internet speed in China is very good. back in 2017 and most major cities in China have fiber optic with 100 Mbps/200 Mbps download connections. International internet speed is not so good, unless you know how to go around the restrictions. So if your going to use bootstrap, I would or will use bootstap local rather than cdn to it.